# Getting most popular posts based on Facebook comments count

Tags: php, comments, facebook

I have modified a widget to display the total number of Facebook comments on a post rather than the total wordpress comments.  I can get that part to show correctly, but I would like to get the most popular posts based on how many Facebook comments there are as I have disabled wordpress comments and am only using the Facebook comments plugin v2.3.

This is the code I have searched and modified from various web posts but I know I'm missing something.  I have also added a field in the database by duplicating the comment_count field and renaming it facebook_comments_count.

Currently I have this code in functions.php, but I doubt I'm putting it in the correct location.

```
add_action('template_redirect', 'updateFBCommentsCount', 1, 1);

function updateFBCommentsCount($post_id) {
    $url = get_permalink($post_id);

    $query = "https://graph.facebook.com/".$url."?fields=comments";
    $responseText = file_get_contents($query);
    $responseJson = json_decode($responseText);

    $commentCount = $responseJson->comments;
    update_post_meta($post_id, 'facebook_comments_count', $commentCount);
}
```

If I could get some direction with this that would be great. I'm not new with php, but new with the backend of wordpress.

Comment: What is the graph request returning?

Comment: You might want to save a timestamp and only check so often - if you keep hammering the API on every request you'll soon end up getting blocked/temporarily suspended (depending on the traffic to your site).

Comment: The graph request returns an integer of the number of comments.

Comment: How do I include a timestamp in this code?  Again, I know some php but I don't really know the wordpress backend.

Comment: @eliwedel You can edit this plug-in [Top Shared Posts on Facebook][1] to retrieve data for `comment_count` rather than `total_count` which uses by default. 


  [1]: https://wordpress.org/plugins/top-shared-posts-on-facebook/